# как сменить значение переменной в условие для всего кода?

Tags: python, aiogram, if, переменные, условия

Имем язык python, библиотеку aiogram и код:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def functionn(message: types.Message):
    Variable = "null"
    if "number: " in message.text:
        Variable = message.text
    elif message.text == "show number":
        await message.reply(Variable)
```

Нужно чтобы после проверки первого условия: `if "number: " in message.text:` переменная `Variable`
применила новое значение и для второго условия, тоесть после проверки: `elif message.text == "show number":` должно показать новое значение после первой проверки  `if "number: " in message.text: Variable = message.text`.

Comment: Очень интересно. но не понятно. Приведите пример На входе текст, на выходе что хотите получить текст

Comment: @СергейШашко, нужно чтобы значение переменной логического выражения первого условия отображалось в логическом выражении второго условия

Comment: Пример преведите

Comment: я пишу боту в лс сообщение, которое сохроняеться у него, потом когда ктото введёт нужную команду, то данное сообщение пришлётся человеку который ввёл нужную команду

Comment: Бля ... . Пример преведите сообщения и что в итоге хотите получить

Comment: да я хз как тебе объяснить. Если хочешь пример кодом то нету, не имею представление как это написать, а задачу могу повторить

Comment: 'я пишу боту в лс сообщение' >>пример сообщения<< 'потом когда ктото введёт нужную команду' >>пример команды<< 'данное сообщение пришлётся человеку' >>пример сообщения<<

Comment: 'я пишу боту в лс сообщение' >>/set_mon расписание пар на понедельник:1. Математика; 2. ООП, 3. Английский<< 'потом когда ктото введёт нужную команду' >>Расписание на понедельник<< или  >>/monday<<'данное сообщение пришлётся человеку ответом' >>расписание пар на понедельник:1. Математика; 2. ООП, 3. Английский<<

Answer (score 0):

Кратко, в общих чертах

```
variable = 'расписание пар на понедельник:1. Математика; 2. ООП, 3. Английский'

@dp.message_handler(commands=['monday'])
    async def monday(message: types.Message):
        clobal variable    
        await message.reply(variable)

@dp.message_handler()
async def functionn(message: types.Message):
    if "Расписание на понедельник" in message.text:
        clobal variable    
        await message.reply(variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен что правильно понял вашу проблему, но попробуйте вместо **elif** везде ставить **if**, в таком случае оба условия будут запущены, и в итоге внутри функции переменная измениться.

Если вы заводите переменную при запуске бота, а потом внутри функции хотите ее изменить, пишите

```
global Variable
```

```
Variable = 'text
```